# python generate ip's to selected files number

Tags: python, file, text, ip

I want to generate a whole ip range and write it to many files as the user want like this

```
How many files : 9
Ip range : 100
```

I want to divide the ip range 100.0.0.0 - 100.255.0.0 to 9 files 1.txt , 2.txt ... etc
and write the result into those files ... and for the remainder i want to write them in the last file

Result :-

```
File1:
100.0.0.0
100.1.0.0
100.2.0.0
100.3.0.0
...
100.27.0.0

File2:
100.28.0.0
...
100.55.0.0

and complete the 9 files
```

I'm writing this code for this process but i don't know how to generate the ip numbers

```
iprange = int(raw_input("IP Range : "))
count = int(raw_input("How much files you want to create ? \n"))
ipnum = 256 / count
extra=256%count
ipnum [-1]=ipnum [-1]+extra
for i,g in enumerate(ipnum):
    with open('ip{0}_{1}'.format(iprange,(i+1)), 'w') as fout:
        fout.writelines(?????)
```

any help

Comment: So do you want as close to 1/9 of the addresses in ech file, or do you want 100.0.0.0 - 100.0.255.255 in one file, 100.1.0.0 - 100.1.255.255 in the next, and 100.10.0.0 - 100.255.255.255 in the last file? Could you define your desired address block size, CIDR-style?

Comment: could you check the result i need in the edited question

Comment: you can consider it like generating a range on numbers from 0 to 255 after the first dot then divide the line numbers on the files numbers in this case it will be 256/9 = 28.4444 . So the script should write each 28 line in the file then the rest on the last file

Answer (score 0):

Your schema by which you want to split does not make total sense to me.  Maybe you can provide a better example.  Also, Python's `netaddr` module will help you.

Comment: you can consider it like generating a range on numbers from 0 to 255 after the first dot then divide the line numbers on the files numbers in this case it will be 256/9 = 28.4444 . So the script should write each 28 line in the file then the rest on the last file

Comment: i used this code to generate the ip's `for i in range(256):
cr1 = ("{1}.{0}" + ".0.0").format(i,iprange)` , but how i can divide them ?

Answer (score -1):

I have created a file and wrote the generated ip's then divided through this code

```
iprange = int(raw_input("IP Range : "))
count = int(raw_input("How much files you want to create ? \n"))
ipnum =[256 / count] * count
extra=256%count
ipnum[-1]=ipnum[-1]+extra
with open('{0}.txt'.format(iprange), 'w') as f:
    for i in range(256):
        cr1 = ("{1}.{0}" + ".0.0\n").format(i,iprange)
        f.write(cr1)
with open('{0}.txt'.format(iprange)) as f:
    for i,g in enumerate(ipnum):
        with open('ip{0}_{1}'.format(iprange,(i+1)), 'w') as fout:
            fout.writelines([next(f) for x in xrange(g)])
```

and horray worked perfectly ;)